# How can I ensure that my domain model's Program class gets used instead of the entry Program class?

Tags: c#

"Program" is a word in my domain. I have a class named `Program` for my domain model. What can happen is the `MyNamespace.Program` entry class gets picked up if I just use `Program` in my code, and do not fully qualify it via `MyNamespace.Areas.SomeArea.Data.Program`. The part that troubles me is that this can result in the application compiling and then erroring at runtime.

I am interested in solutions that keep me from compiling an application that will exception at runtime. The best solution I've thought of is renaming the MyNamespace.Program entry class to something else.

Addendum:

This question's original title was "Can I name the .NET Core Program class something else". Unfortunately that resulted in multiple down votes, and some surprisingly opinionated responses to what I thought was a simple question. So instead of asking that question I've rewritten this question as a description of my specific problem, hoping it might be more helpful to anyone who stumbles upon it in the future.

Comment: Why don't you try and see? But yes, you should be able to.

Comment: Why is this a problem? The two classes should have different namespaces. Renaming `Program` is pure evil - will you remember in one year that you renamed the class to something else? Will the support guy know this?

Comment: Flawless victory @john it worked.

Comment: Evil huh and the downvotes!? It's been a while since I posted a question on Stackoverflow, but it seems the site has really gone down hill since then. Thanks to all who have offered positive contributions. To everyone else. Go troll somewhere else please.

Comment: I rewrote this question as a description of my problem instead of asking a question (with background) I thought would address said problem. I really don't understand the down votes and wish someone would have taken the time to explain them to me. This is my attempt to remedy the mistake I think others think that I made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The thing you can't change, though, is the Main method name (and signature, to certain extent). Besides, if you have two Main methods in different classes you'll have to tell the compiler which is the entry point to your application.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any of this issues, if you declare your namespaces correctly.

```
using MyNamespace;
using MyNamespace.Domain;

namespace MyNamespace.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext { }
}
```

This may confuse the compiler as `Programm` may be defined in `MyNamespace` and in `MyNamespace.Domain`.

```
using MyNamespace;

namespace MyNamespace.Data
{
    using MyNamespace.Domain;
    // or alternatively, because Domain is part of MyNamespace
    using Domain;

    public class MyDbContext : DbContext { }
}
```

The later one shouldn't cause any confusion issues, because if you have ambiguous/conflicting names, the compiler will take it from the inner using and if it doesn't find it there, look at the outer usings.

#### On a side note

`Program`  doesn't sound like a very good name for a domain model, `App`/`Application` (Software) or `Broadcast` (TV) etc. imho

Comment: Maybe you just **try the stuff out**, before claiming it's wrong. When put `using MyNamespace.Domain` inside the namespace rather than above it, `Program` will **always** refer to your domain model and not the `Program` as program entry

Comment: Also knowing how to use namespaces usings will help you avoid with future questions when your domain model is called `XmlDocument`, `Application` or some other common type name used by the framework, or a 3rd party library where you can't simply "rename the type" (though you can alias it with usings)

Comment: Doing what you describe doesn't address the fact that the program can still be compiled and then error at runtime. If you care to take a look, I've updated the question to clarify that I'm looking for a solution that keeps me from compiling an application that will fail at runtime due to C# picking up the wrong Program class under the circumstances described.

Comment: Sooner or later you'll run into a different type name which collides with a domain model name. Also the answer is more an alternative for others -less aggressive- users who come across the problem rather then to the specific question of yours. But there are also other ways to solve it, i.e.change the namespace of the `Program` class, i.e.instead of having full qualified name of `MyCompany.Program` and `MyCompany.Domain.Program`, you could change the namespaces to `MyCompany.Web.Program` and the issue shouldn't happen either. It's a common convention to surfix ASP.NET Projects `.Web`or `WebApi`

Comment: Saying collisions happen misses the point. I don't follow the second sentence of your latest comment. I'd suggest that your answer as it is now is a side note and doesn't address the original question or current problem description. On the otherhand, I appreciate your comment that moving Program out of MyCompany namespace to something like MyCompany.Bootstrap.Program is a worthwhile answer to avoiding this problem.